# GetFileAsync and GetSliceAsync Results in Corrupted .pptx File - how to properly encode and decode?

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js

I'm attempting to get a whole .pptx document as described here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint?tabs=powerpoint) from an add-in and upload it to SharePoint. This results in a corrupted pptx file that when repaired states the PowerPoint can't read some of the content in the presentation.

Below is my code for retrieving the file slices, joining them, encoding to base64 string, sending to the backend and decoding:

```
FRONTEND

  fileUpload = () => {
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync("compressed",
    { sliceSize: 65536 /*64 KB*/ }, (result) => this.updateFileAsyncState(result));
  }

updateFileAsyncState = (result) => {
  if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      // Get the File object from the result.
      const myFile = result.value;
      const sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
      let slicesReceived = 0;
      let gotAllSlices = true;
      let docDataSlices = []
      

      this.getFileSlice(myFile, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docDataSlices, slicesReceived);
  } else {
    console.log(result)
  }
}

  getFileSlice = (file, nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docDataSlices, slicesReceived) => {
    file.getSliceAsync(nextSlice, (result) => this.updateSliceAsyncState(result, file, nextSlice, docDataSlices, slicesReceived, sliceCount, gotAllSlices))
  }

  updateSliceAsyncState = (result, file, nextSlice, docDataSlices, slicesReceived, sliceCount, gotAllSlices) => {
    if (result.status === "succeeded") {
      if (!gotAllSlices) {
        return;
      }

      docDataSlices[result.value.index] = result.value.data;

      if (++slicesReceived == sliceCount) {
        file.closeAsync()
        this.sendFile(docDataSlices);
      } else {
        this.getFileSlice(file, ++nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docDataSlices, slicesReceived)
      }
    }
}

sendFile = (docDataSlices) => {
  let docdata = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < docDataSlices.length; i++) {
      docdata = docdata.concat(docDataSlices[i]);
  }

  const encodedData = window.btoa(docdata.map((d) => String.fromCharCode(d)).join(''));

  const formData = new FormData();
  const date = new Date();
  
  formData.append('file', encodedData);
  formData.append('filename', this.state.file);
  formData.append('userEmail', this.state.userEmail);
  formData.append('uploadDate', date.toISOString());

  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open("POST", "http://localhost:5000/file/upload_file");

  if (this.state.selectedFolder) {
    const fold = this.state.projectFolders.filter(fold => fold.Name === this.state.selectedFolder);
    formData.append('folderPath', fold[0].ServerRelativeUrl);
  }

  request.send(formData);
}

BACKEND

const uploadDocument = async (req, res) => {
    const { folderPath, userEmail, uploadDate, file, filename } = req.body;

    const fileDecodeBuff = Buffer.from([file], 'base64');

    const fileData = await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativePath(folderPath).files.addChunked(filename, fileDecodeBuff, undefined, true);

}
```

Please let know what is the proper way to encode and decode the byte array returned from getFileAsync and getSliceAsync to render the document properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured this out - the issue was the full byte array was not being sent to the backend. I converted the array to an Uint8Array in the frontend and converted it to a array buffer in the backend and the file was successfully uploaded.